# I can't use <h1> inside <script>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to use React.js but when i try to use a balise like 'h1' or a 'div' inside a script balise, the rest of the code is not taken into account. I have seen a lot of forums using it but i don't understand how it works.

```
<html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script src="reactJS/build/react.js"></script>
<script src="reactJS/build/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script>
    function formatName(user) {
        return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
    }

    const name = 'Josh Perez', 
    element = <h1>Hello, {name}</h1>;

    ReactDOM.render(
      element,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
</script>
```

The "/" in the 12th line makes the rest of the code not usable and it doesn't act like a script balise anymore.

I thank you in advance for the help.
(Sorry if my english is really poor aswell)

Comment: Hi Quent, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to add `babel` to work with `JSX`,

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Also make sure to add `type="text/babel"` on your `script` tag.

```
<script type="text/babel">  //Add type here
    function formatName(user) {
        return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
    }

    const name = 'Josh Perez', 
    element = <h1>Hello, {name}</h1>;

    ReactDOM.render(
      element,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
</script>
```

For more information check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html).

Comment: I didn't know about the src, i don't think it was written in forums i went. Thank you very much !